# How do I sort binary key value pairs at fixed byte offsets using the Linux sort utility?

Tags: sort

I want to sort a 20GB **binary** file that contains 30-byte key and 20 byte value placed in a contiguous manner. *Everything is on a single line.* I would like to specify the key length the sort must use for comparison and the record size. So that, when a key has moved, the value associated with it is also moved.

Ideally, I would not like to modify the file in any way (i.e add separators between Key and value). The file looks like `KVKVKVKVKVKV`. Single line binary file.

Hexdump of first 200B of the 20GB file:

```
# hexdump -n 200 -C 20gbUnsorted
00000000  54 65 73 74 69 6E 67 31  32 33 65 08 00 60 83 6b  |Testing123e..`.k|
00000010  39 2c d5 8b 8f 5e 55 96  18 55 e7 9b 87 f0 22 83  |9,...^U..U....".|
00000020  a4 66 b6 aa b1 f9 e0 ca  cf 1e 26 b3 29 2a fd 10  |.f........&.)*..|
00000030  64 bb 18 b5 6a c0 7d 6f  65 6b 1d 2f 43 0d 57 bd  |d...j.}oek./C.W.|
00000040  e7 e4 7d 81 f3 6a 6d d2  67 94 8b bc 23 97 bf e2  |..}..jm.g...#...|
00000050  8c 33 4e 4a d8 2b 8e 70  16 62 93 cf aa 01 16 bf  |.3NJ.+.p.b......|
00000060  da 3b b1 ab 95 e0 e4 82  62 b3 ed fe 04 47 b5 7f  |.;......b....G..|
00000070  77 b1 3a 35 87 fb e7 90  42 e3 c4 06 d6 8e 9f d2  |w.:5....B.......|
00000080  c7 f3 f6 39 0d 9d 0d ce  13 fb 83 42 e1 52 81 2e  |...9.......B.R..|
00000090  99 4b 4b 40 3a 16 7a 2a  7c 93 c3 84 1d e1 93 0a  |.KK@:.z*|.......|
000000a0  0d b2 07 f4 eb 9e 04 b5  9e d8 77 d9 a1 a0 67 a1  |..........w...g.|
000000b0  01 fa 8d 8d 4c 04 5b ee  a3 00 6f b4 20 50 a4 e6  |....L.[...o. P..|
000000c0  5b b3 cc 40 83 eb b2 ad                           |[..@....|
000000c8
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: @thanasisp perhaps `sort` is not the right tool to use here. I am just exploring if one can use it sort this kind of files.

Comment: Okay, great. So your first key is from `54` to `F0`, the first value from `22` to `BB`; the second value from `18` to `E2` and it needs to be sorted before the first one (along with it's value field), because 0x18 < 0xE2?

Comment: That's right! @Philippos

Comment: This is a 20GB data file? When expanded through something such as `hexdump` you're going to get a little over a 3.5x increase in size. That's a 70GB stream of data to pipe into `sort`.

Comment: You are right @roaima I planned on using sort because it has `--parallel` option but not sure if I can use that with the solutions suggested below.

Answer (score 6):

This feels ugly, but it should work:

```bsh
hexdump -v -e '50/1 "%02x " "\n"' file.bin | sort | xxd -p -r > file-sorted.bin
```

You do a `hexdump` grouped by 50 bytes per line, do an ordinary `sort` of those lines, and reconvert it using `xxd -r`.

I didn't care about sorting for only the first 30 bytes, because if they are identical, the order is open and I choose to continue sorting by the value.

Comment: I edited your command to avoid trying to build a 20GB command-line argument (which will exceed `exec` limits on all Unix and Linux systems I'm aware of).  I also removed the need for the initial offset by using `xxd -p`

Answer (score 5):

IMO, easier to manage in a programming language that makes it easy to read/write binary files. For (an esoteric) example, Tcl:

```
tclsh <<'END_TCL'
    set fh [open file.bin rb]
    while {true} {
        set kv [read $fh 50]
        if {[string length $kv] != 50} break
        lappend kvs $kv
    }
    close $fh

    set fh [open file_sorted.bin wb]
    foreach kv [lsort $kvs] {puts -nonewline $fh $kv}
    close $fh
END_TCL
```

Here's the input file:

```
$ ls -l file.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 200 Apr 20 16:07 file.bin

$ od -c -w50 file.bin
0000000   T   e   s   t   i   n   g   1   2   3   e  \b  \0   ` 203   k   9   ,   � 213 217   ^   U 226 030   U   � 233 207   �   " 203   �   f   �   �   �   �   �   �   � 036   &   �   )   *   � 020   d   �
0000062 030   �   j   �   }   o   e   k 035   /   C  \r   W   �   �   �   } 201   �   j   m   �   g 224 213   �   # 227   �   � 214   3   N   J   �   + 216   p 026   b 223   �   � 001 026   �   �   ;   �   �
0000144 225   �   � 202   b   �   �   � 004   G   � 177   w   �   :   5 207   �   � 220   B   �   � 006   � 216 237   �   �   �   �   9  \r 235  \r   � 023   � 203   B   �   R 201   . 231   K   K   @   : 026
0000226   z   *   | 223   � 204 035   � 223  \n  \r   �  \a   �   � 236 004   � 236   �   w   �   �   �   g   � 001   � 215 215   L 004   [   �   �  \0   o   �       P   �   �   [   �   �   @ 203   �   �   �
0000310
```

And the output file:

```
$ ls -l file_sorted.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 200 Apr 20 16:11 file_sorted.bin

$ od -c -w50 file_sorted.bin
0000000 030   �   j   �   }   o   e   k 035   /   C  \r   W   �   �   �   } 201   �   j   m   �   g 224 213   �   # 227   �   � 214   3   N   J   �   + 216   p 026   b 223   �   � 001 026   �   �   ;   �   �
0000062   T   e   s   t   i   n   g   1   2   3   e  \b  \0   ` 203   k   9   ,   � 213 217   ^   U 226 030   U   � 233 207   �   " 203   �   f   �   �   �   �   �   �   � 036   &   �   )   *   � 020   d   �
0000144   z   *   | 223   � 204 035   � 223  \n  \r   �  \a   �   � 236 004   � 236   �   w   �   �   �   g   � 001   � 215 215   L 004   [   �   �  \0   o   �       P   �   �   [   �   �   @ 203   �   �   �
0000226 225   �   � 202   b   �   �   � 004   G   � 177   w   �   :   5 207   �   � 220   B   �   � 006   � 216 237   �   �   �   �   9  \r 235  \r   � 023   � 203   B   �   R 201   . 231   K   K   @   : 026
0000310
```

---

for the curious, I created the input file from the question like this (bash):

```bsh
for hx in \
    54 65 73 74 69 6E 67 31  32 33 65 08 00 60 83 6b \
    39 2c d5 8b 8f 5e 55 96  18 55 e7 9b 87 f0 22 83 \
    a4 66 b6 aa b1 f9 e0 ca  cf 1e 26 b3 29 2a fd 10 \
    64 bb 18 b5 6a c0 7d 6f  65 6b 1d 2f 43 0d 57 bd \
    e7 e4 7d 81 f3 6a 6d d2  67 94 8b bc 23 97 bf e2 \
    8c 33 4e 4a d8 2b 8e 70  16 62 93 cf aa 01 16 bf \
    da 3b b1 ab 95 e0 e4 82  62 b3 ed fe 04 47 b5 7f \
    77 b1 3a 35 87 fb e7 90  42 e3 c4 06 d6 8e 9f d2 \
    c7 f3 f6 39 0d 9d 0d ce  13 fb 83 42 e1 52 81 2e \
    99 4b 4b 40 3a 16 7a 2a  7c 93 c3 84 1d e1 93 0a \
    0d b2 07 f4 eb 9e 04 b5  9e d8 77 d9 a1 a0 67 a1 \
    01 fa 8d 8d 4c 04 5b ee  a3 00 6f b4 20 50 a4 e6 \
    5b b3 cc 40 83 eb b2 ad                         
do printf "\x$hx"; done > file.bin
```

Comment: With a 20GB input plus the overhead of string objects in a high-level language, the list probably won't fit in RAM. Most high-level languages' sort function is not optimized for huge inputs and have very poor performance when the data doesn't fit in RAM. In contrast, many implementations of the `sort` utility (at least GNU and FreeBSD) do support external sort and therefore have good performance on data that's larger than RAM.

Comment: Ah, 20GB is new information. Sounds like a job for a database. SQLite perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

This dumps your file in hex in readable 30 and 20 bytes strings:

```
cat mybinaryfile.bin | LC_ALL=C hexdump -v -e '50/1 "%02x " "\n"' | \
while read -r line ; do echo 'K="'"${line::89}"'", V="'"${line:90}"'"' ; done
```

The LC_ALL is to output in an always readable character set.

The hexdump: -v disables the suppression of identical lines.
The -e makes the format string possible, which says 'break it down in 50 byte chunks, print those terminated with a new line (the \n); within the 50 byte block, print 1 byte at the time formatted as hex (the x), two characters wide (the two), if needed prefixed with a leading zero. (If you change the 'x' in '_p' you get printable characters in stead of hex.)

The while reads those 50 byte lines and breaks them down in 30 and 20 byte chunks, which it does by using bash Parameter Expansion, first by cutting off all characters beyond the 89th, the '"line::89}"' and then by cutting off all characters before the 90th, the '"${line:90}"'.

Now the sort. Adding a plain

```
| sort
```

Will of course sort on the first column, while a

```
| sort -t , -k 2,2
```

will determine the , to be a field separator and the -k 2,2 will direct the sort to sort by the second (value) field.

So the complete command, with readable output, sorted by value, will be:

```
cat mybinaryfile.bin | LC_ALL=C hexdump -v -e '50/1 "%02x " "\n"' | \
while read -r line ; do echo 'K="'"${line::89}"'", V="'"${line:90}"'"' ; done | \
sort -t , -k 2,2
```

Cheers.

Example using my kernel:

```
sudo dd if=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | \
LC_ALL=C hexdump -v -e '50/1 "%_p" "\n"' | while read -r line ; do \
echo 'K="'"${line::29}"'", V="'"${line:30}"'"' ; done | sort -t , -k 2,2
K="..........U.", V=""
K=".........N}..................", V="...... ... ........."
K=".............................", V=".................. ."
K="....>.............. .P`......", V="..................."
K="...........P}.....X..........", V="...................."
K="...............setup...;.....", V=".;.................."
K="MZ.............1....@.. .t...", V="......1............."
K=".P`.reloc.. ....=.. ....=....", V=".........@..B.compa"
K="t. ....=.. ....=.............", V="@..B.text.....}..>.."
K="press any key to reboot......", V="E..d..............."
K="..............Use a boot load", V="r....Remove disk and"
```

Comment: You don't need to `cat` the file, `hexdump` can take it as an argument. More importantly, this seems to be simply separating the key/value pairs into temporary variables, but the question is asking how to _sort_ them, preferably in the same original format.

Comment: A 'cat inputfile | process1 | process2' is easier to explain and follow for someone less acquainted with a command line as a 'process1 < inputfile | process2'.

Comment: Oh, you don't even need the redirect. Many tools, including `hexdump` are designed to take file names as input. and `command input_file` is, if anything, even clearer than `cat input_file | command`. But that's minor, it's just a classic [UUoC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award), so I pointed it out. Thanks for adding the `sort` stuff, that's a clear improvement!

Comment: @terdon: I guess you meant _take file names as **arguments**_, rather than as input?  Some commands take file names as input (notably `xargs`, of course) but I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, as arguments in this case, see my very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the size of data, I would suggest using a divide and conquer approach.

Divide your file into manageable chunks - for example you can use @glenn jackman's approach, but instead of reading the entire file at once just read the first 10 million key-value pairs (or however many your computer can handle at once), sort them, and dump them to tempfile1. Then clear the data from RAM, read the next chunk, sort it, and dump to tempfile2. Repeat until you are through the 20GB file.

Now you have a bunch of smaller, individually sorted files that we need to put back together. Luckily this step is (relatively) easy, and most importantly don't care about data size.

If you have two sequences that are individually sorted, then all you need to do to combine them into a single sorted sequence is to look at the two top elements and always just take the first-by-sort element. Doing this only requires three open files (the two you are reading from and one for writing the result), and enough memory to hold the two top elements.

Unfortunately I don't know any tools that can do this for you, so you may have to program it yourself.

Comment: `sort -m` will handle a merge sort. Apparently.